# How can I convert layer to smart object in Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop

This script converts the active layer into a smart object:

```
createSmartObject(app.activeDocument.activeLayer);
function createSmartObject(layer)
{
    var idnewPlacedLayer = stringIDToTypeID( 'newPlacedLayer' );
    executeAction(idnewPlacedLayer, undefined, DialogModes.NO);
}
```

My question: Is there a shorter way to code this?

Comment: Only way to get a Smart Object via a script I have found in the JS docs is to open a File object as a smart object. So I guess you could copy the layer to another document, insert it into main file as Smart object and then discard then additional document. Read more at p.49 of https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf

Answer (score 3):

```
createSmartObject();
function createSmartObject() {
    var idnewPlacedLayer = stringIDToTypeID( 'newPlacedLayer' );
    executeAction(idnewPlacedLayer, undefined, DialogModes.NO);
}
```

You don't need to pass the layer into the function--it acts upon whatever the current active layer happens to be.