# Convert all existing clipping masks to smart object in Photoshop Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

Is it possible to convert all existing clipping masks to smart objects in Photoshop using Javascript?

[image]

I mean converting the image and its shape clipping mask to single smart object.

Comment: There are no layer masks on your screenshot. Did you mean clipping masks? Yes, it's possible: you need to iterate through layers and add to layer selection the ones that are grouped, then just convert selected to SO

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are right. I was going to say clipping masks. I corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible: Although this script just looks for a clipping mask and the layer it's ascribed to. No groups as I don't know what your PSD is like. But you get the idea.

The real answers were [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617888/how-can-i-convert-layer-to-smart-object-in-photoshop) and [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/script-to-select-multiple-layers/td-p/10663427?page=1) and [here](https://www.ps-scripts.com/viewtopic.php?t=9103)

```
// select the source image
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

var smart = false;
for (var i = 0; i< numOfLayers-1; i++)
{
  //select that layer as you go along
  srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.artLayers[i];

  if (is_clipping_layer(srcDoc.layers[i]) == true)
  {
    // alert(thisLayer.name + "\n    " + srcDoc.layers[i+1].name);
    select_layer(srcDoc.layers[i+1].name, true)
    smart = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(smart == true)
{
  convert_to_smart_object();
}



function is_clipping_layer()
{
  var l = activeDocument.activeLayer;
  return (l.grouped == true && l.kind == LayerKind.NORMAL)
}

function convert_to_smart_object()
{
  var idnewPlacedLayer = stringIDToTypeID( 'newPlacedLayer' );
  executeAction(idnewPlacedLayer, undefined, DialogModes.NO);
}


function select_layer(nm, add)
{   
  try
  {

    var r = new ActionReference();
    r.putName(stringIDToTypeID("layer"), nm);
    var d = new ActionDescriptor();
    d.putReference(stringIDToTypeID("null"), r);
    if (add == true) d.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("selectionModifier"), stringIDToTypeID("selectionModifierType"), stringIDToTypeID("addToSelection"));
    executeAction(stringIDToTypeID("select"), d, DialogModes.NO);
  }

  catch (eeek)
  {
    alert(eeek);
  }
}
```